# Assigning a menu to a view page in drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I have 3 menus named main menu, microsite menu, supernav menu.
I am creating a view page and wanted to include microsite menu. but the view page is taking the default main menu, how can i remove the main menu and embed the microsite menu.
I cant see any option like selecting the available menus in a view page settings.
How can i achieve this?

Is there any option to embed the microsite menu using php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a menu was creation, and build as block .. thats true?

if yes .. go to block --> find a microsite menu block --> configuration ---> Show block on specific pages ---> select option tow (Only the listed pages) --> set in text area page view name ..

and go to main menu block --> do same last steps exeption select choice one ( All pages except those listed ) and set page view name too

also you can use a **Context module**  its very very nice for do this action [Go here](https://www.drupal.org/project/context)
its can be set any condition, place, rule, pages, for any block ...

by php code you can use a code like this in block configare

```
if(arg(0) == 'page1') {
  return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Thanks buddy... your answer is exactly i wanted... i didnt know that we can view name in block configuration.. Thanks a lot

Comment: you are welcome mate, Im very happy to read that.. thanks a lot ..

Go a head, good luck ..^^